# unable to create a cluster/plan to a remote server in R

Tags: r, linux, ssh, cluster-computing

Trying (still) to get a cluster running. I have two Linux (Ubuntu) computers, the server is "laptop". Pretty sure ssh works, with key authentication, I can ssh to "laptop" without a password from command line. ssh_exec_wait works, e.g.,

```
session <- ssh_connect("laptop")
a <- ssh_exec_wait(session, command = "whoami")
ssh_disconnect(session)
```

works. I've gone through the doc (A future for R), works fine until I get to cluster futures.

```
plan(cluster, workers = c("localhost"))
```

works fine, but

```
plan(cluster, workers = c("laptop"))
```

gives the error:

```
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 11968
List of 2
 $ node_idx: int 1
 $ node    :List of 5
  ..$ con         : 'sockconn' int 3
  .. ..- attr(*, "conn_id")=<externalptr> 
  ..$ host        : chr "laptop"
  .. ..- attr(*, "localhost")= logi FALSE
  ..$ rank        : int 1
  ..$ rshlogfile  : NULL
  ..$ session_info:List of 6
  .. ..$ r      :List of 15
  .. .. ..$ platform      : chr "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
  .. .. ..$ arch          : chr "x86_64"
  .. .. ..$ os            : chr "linux-gnu"
  .. .. ..$ system        : chr "x86_64, linux-gnu"
  .. .. ..$ status        : chr ""
  .. .. ..$ major         : chr "3"
  .. .. ..$ minor         : chr "6.3"
  .. .. ..$ year          : chr "2020"
  .. .. ..$ month         : chr "02"
  .. .. ..$ day           : chr "29"
  .. .. ..$ svn rev       : chr "77875"
  .. .. ..$ language      : chr "R"
  .. .. ..$ version.string: chr "R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)"
  .. .. ..$ nickname      : chr "Holding the Windsock"
  .. .. ..$ os.type       : chr "unix"
  .. ..$ system :List of 8
  .. .. ..$ sysname       : chr "Linux"
  .. .. ..$ release       : chr "5.3.0-46-generic"
  .. .. ..$ version       : chr "#38~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 31 04:17:56 UTC 2020"
  .. .. ..$ nodename      : chr "laptop"
  .. .. ..$ machine       : chr "x86_64"
  .. .. ..$ login         : chr "mark"
  .. .. ..$ user          : chr "mark"
  .. .. ..$ effective_user: chr "mark"
  .. ..$ libs   : chr [1:4] "/home/mark/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6" "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/library"
  .. ..$ pkgs   : NULL
  .. ..$ pwd    : chr "/home/mark"
  .. ..$ process:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ pid: int 2809
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "SOCKnode"
Error: Initialization of plan() failed, because the test future used for validation failed. The reason was: Unexpected result (of class ‘NULL’ != ‘FutureResult’) retrieved for ClusterFuture future (label = ‘future-plan-test’, expression = ‘NA’): . This suggests that the communication with ClusterFuture worker (‘SOCKnode’ #1) is out of sync.
```

I assume the first line is the real error message:

```
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 11968
```

Do I need to manually set the port?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the warning

```
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 11968
```

is caused by a hanging R process on that port (it could be another process of course but it's likely that the future package created it). If you kill the process on `laptop`, the port should become available again.

You can check by manually running

```
ssh -R 11968:localhost:11968 laptop
```